# Proof that $\frac{d(\sin x)}{dx} = \cos x$ for $\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \pi$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Let us assume that $x$ is an angle that lies in the second quadrant i.e. $\dfrac{\pi}{2} < x < \pi$.

We have to prove that $\dfrac{d(\sin x)}{dx} = \cos x$. I will use the unit circle to prove this. The method will be like the one used by Grant Sanderson of [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw) in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0_qX4VJhMQ&list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr&index=3), which is a part of his [Essence of Calculus](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr) series.

The angles are measured in radians. In the diagram below, I have marked the angle $x$ and $dx$ on the unit circle. The angle $dx$ approaches $0$, so it is very very small but for the sake of clarity, I have made it considerably large.

[image: Figure - 1]

Now, since $dx$ is actually really small, we can approximate arc $AB$ as a straight line approximately perpendicular to $OA$. We are measuring the angles in radians and we have a unit circle, so its radius is $1 \text{ units}$. Hence, the length of arc (now line segment) $AB$ is $\dfrac{\theta}{r}$, where $\theta$ is $\angle AOB$ i.e. $dx$ and $r = 1 \text{ units}$. So, $AB = \dfrac{dx}{1} = dx$.

Now, $d(\sin x) = \sin(x+dx)-\sin x$ which is the change in the ordinate of $A$ and $B$.

[image: Figure - 2]

Now, $AP = d(\sin x)$  and $AB = dx$. Also, $\triangle APB \sim \triangle AOQ$. So, $\angle BAP = \angle OAQ = \pi - x$. $\cos(\angle BAP) = \dfrac{AP}{AB} = \dfrac{d(\sin x)}{dx}$. And $\cos(\angle BAP) = \cos (\pi - x) = -\cos x$

So, $\dfrac{d(\sin x)}{dx} = -\cos x$ which is not the case at all, since $\dfrac{d(\sin x)}{dx}$ will be negative as $\sin(x+dx) < \sin x$ but the sign of $-\cos x$ will be positive as $\cos x < 0$.

So, what mistake did I make here?

According to me, the mistake was in assuming that $AP = d(\sin x)$. I think that $AP$ should be $|d(\sin x)|$. And as $d(\sin x) < 0 \implies |d(\sin x)| = -d(\sin x)$. This fixes everything but I still want to verify if this indeed is the cause of the error.

Thanks!

PS : Let me know if I should justify why $\triangle APB \sim \triangle OQA$ to make the question clearer.

PPS : It is necessary to prove that differentiating $\sin x$ with respect to $x$ gives $\cos x$ for all 4 quadrants when proving using the unit circle, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$d(\sin x)= \sin(x+dx)-\sin x \lt 0$$as $\sin x$ is decreasing in $\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right)$. You’re absolutely right in spotting your mistake. When you claim $$AP=d(\sin x)$$ , you’re assigning a negative value to a length, and so you *do* need an absolute sign there. $$AP=|d(\sin x)| =-d(\sin x)$$

Comment: Thanks! What do you say about the PPS?

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Yes, it is. You prove it for  the smallest range of angles for which $\sin x$ is surjective, aka it reaches all values in $(-1,1)$, which is $[0,2\pi)$. Then for any angle other than that, the $2\pi$-periodicity argument follows.